# test class for before update trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test

Hello I am new to test classes in apex and I need to create a test class for below trigger

```
trigger prevent on Quote (before update) {

id cuser = userinfo.getuserid(); 
id iduser;
id profilo = userinfo.getProfileId();
id profiloadmin = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator'].id;

if (profilo==profiloadmin) {
    return;
}

for (quote q : trigger.new) {
    opportunity opp = [select stagename from opportunity where id =:q.opportunityid];
     try {
    iduser = [select userid from opportunityteammember
         where teammemberrole='Proposal' and opportunityid=:q.opportunityid and userid=:cuser].userid;
    } catch (exception e) {


    }

     if (opp.stagename=='Proposal' && iduser==null) {

        q.adderror('Trattativa in fase PROPOSAL: impossibile modificare');
    }
}
```

}

I have tried with below test class and Iam able to pass the test but no code coverage is recorded.Its 0 percent.Can some one help me explaining what am I missing

```
 @isTest
private class Testprevent {

    static testmethod void test1(){
        test.startTest();

            Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; 
            User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='stan@testorg.com');
            Insert u;



        Opportunity op= new Opportunity();
        op.Name= 'abc';
        op.StageName='Open';
        op.Trattativa__c = 'Automotive';
        op.CloseDate = date.valueOf('2017-11-12');
        op.Tipo_di_Trattativa__c = 'Cross Selling';
        op.Volumi_Sinistri_S__c = '<5000';
        insert op;

        OpportunityTeamMember otm = new OpportunityTeamMember (OpportunityId =  op.Id,UserId = u.Id,TeamMemberRole = 'role');
        insert otm;

        Quote q = new Quote();
        q.Name='abc';
        q.Pricing_matrix__c = true;
        q.Pricing__c = 1000;
        q.OpportunityId = op.Id;
        insert q;


        test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: it's a `before update` trigger, you are not doing any updates.

Comment: @Vara you must need to update  record to cover before update event. add next statement in your code.  `q.Name='abc2'; update q; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute your part of update inside

```
 system.runAs(p ){
      update q;
 }
```

**or**

```
 system.runAs(u){
      update q;
 }
```

and use System.assertEquals();  whatever you want to check here.